# Bootstrap CSS - Can't Get Background Color and Image Together

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap with Rails and can't get the brackground color and image to show up together. I have a custom CSS stylesheet where I'm trying to edit the body to have a dark background with a small image in the bottom right corner, like this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 55px;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url('waves.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
}
```

Problem is that the image doesn't show up, just the background. If I remove the 'background-color' it shows up and looks perfect, but I can't get them together. I know I'm missing something small (probably stupid too). Appreciate the help.

Comment: Why do you think is something related to Bootstrap? Have you tried to comment out bootstrap inclusion in your application.css an this fixed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```
body {    
    padding-top: 55px;
    background: #2e2e2e url(waves.png) right bottom no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Tried that too. No luck. Thanks the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `waves.png` file in `/assets/images` and replace `url('waves.png')` with this:

```
background-image: image-url('waves.png');
```

I'm assuming you're using assets pipeline and your CSS file is preprocessed by Sass (the stylesheet filename ends with *.css.scss*), for more information I suggest you to read the [Asset Pipeline Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using the asset pipeline with Sass. and the image was already in /assets/images. I had used the url('...') to reference images earlier in the css and it worked so I went with it. Tried using image-path('waves.png') and but same result. I'm stumped.

Comment: Sorry, actually it was image-url not image-path (the first one returns the whole CSS rule the second just the path). Maybe it could help. A question: You can see the image in development environment? Have you tried to precompile the assets running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the file extension is .css.erb

```
body {
    padding-top: 55px;
    background: #2e2e2e url('<%= asset_path('waves.png') %>') fixed no-repeat right bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the environment you're in, but have you tried **!important** ? It adds priority in case there are styles with different values applied somewhere later in code.

```
body {
  ...
  background-color: #2e2e2e !important;
  background-image: url('waves.png') !important;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hm hadn't thought of that. Unfortunately still no luck :/